# How to display flutter view on top of Native using MethodChannel?

Tags: flutter

I'm following the Flutter example 'Platform_view',
Using MethodChannel I'm able to communicate between Native code and Flutter code.
My scenario:
When a button press happen in native code I want to run a method in flutter which in turn launches a full screen view on top of the Native application.

My code in flutter:

```
_methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) {
      if (call.method == "launchSecondView") {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          SecondView view = SecondView();
          view.callback = () {
            _methodChannel.invokeMethod("callbackFromSecond");
          };
        })
        );
      }
    });
```

This handler gets called but the Navigator.push() is not displaying the second screen..